# Null pointer exception new JSONobject(String)

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver that get's a JSONObject from the intent in the onRecieve method. It then get's some data from the JSONObject.

```
try {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            jsonData = bundle.getString("com.parse.Data");

            object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            action = object.getString("action");
            id = object.getString("id");

            userQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", id);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
```

When I run the app, it cause a null pointer exception here...

```
object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
```

I ran the debugger and put a stop at

```
userQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", id);
```

Object isn't null, and neither is action, id, or jsonData. I'm kind of confused about this. Here's the next block of code that runs after this...

```
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                user = parseUsers.get(0);
                if(action.equals(connectAction)){
                    if(!connectedB){
                        connectedB = true;
                            Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                            broadcast.setAction(yesAction);
                            broadcast.putExtra("extra","yes");
                            context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);

                    }

                }
            }

        });
```

This just searches Parse for a user that has the same object id. Then once it finds one, it send a broadcast to another broadcast receiver I have in another activity. There's no other code after this. Here's the log cat.

```
          04-15 23:04:30.983  11802-11802/joke.app.randomchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: joke.app.randomchat, PID: 11802
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver joke.app.randomchat.MessageReciever: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2580)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
        at joke.app.randomchat.MessageReciever.onReceive(MessageReciever.java:57)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573)
```

Line 57 is the line I talked about above. How can I fix this?

Here's the values when i stop it at userQuery...

```
Bundle[{com.parse.Data={"id":"at790nlYIN","action":"joke.app.randomchat.intent.CONNECT","push_hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}, com.parse.Channel=null}]
```

This is object

```
{"action":"joke.app.randomchat.intent.CONNECT","id":"at790nlYIN","push_hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}
```

Action string

```
joke.app.randomchat.intent.CONNECT
```

Id String

```
at790nlYIN
```

jsonData

```
{"id":"at790nlYIN","action":"joke.app.randomchat.intent.CONNECT","push_hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `jsonData` is not null?

Comment: Yes. That's what I thought it was at first, but it contains the right information.

Comment: you may want to show the content of jsonData if it is not too large, or just a portion of it.

Comment: Check that the json string you are receiving is valid.

Comment: Is com.parse.Data the key for the string you're sending via the intent?

Comment: I updated the question and added what the values are after stopping it at userqquery.whereequalto

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));


    action = jsonData .getString("action");
    id = jsonData .getString("id");

    userQuery.whereEqualTo("objectId", id);

} catch (JSONException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i just figured out the issue. It wasn't with jsonData, or the JSONObject. In this code...

```
userQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
            user = parseUsers.get(0);
            if(action.equals(connectAction)){
                if(!connectedB){
                    connectedB = true;
                        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                        broadcast.setAction(yesAction);
                        broadcast.putExtra("extra","yes");
                        context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);

                }

            }
        }

    });
```

I send a broadcast to another receiver, but set the action to the wrong action. So it called this receiver again, and the intent didn't have anything in com.parse.Data. Once I changed

```
broadcast.setAction(yesAction);
```

to

```
broadcast.setAction(receivedUpdate);
```

it worked perfectly.